# Table './mysql/proc' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, database, crash

When i perform any procedure creation or update operation to mysql DB, i am getting the below error

Table './mysql/proc' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tried to run mysql isam recover using below command -
myisamchk -q -r /var/lib/mysql/mysql/proc

But the issue still persists.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try these:

```
mysqlcheck --auto-repair -A -u username -ppassword
```

Inside MySQL terminal

```
repair table mysql.proc;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html
Modify the my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html

Comment: After proc table is repaired using 
"repair table mysql.proc;"
Issue is resolved..

Answer (score 0):

The above answer also applicable to other business related tables -

example -
 Table './dev/bank_accounts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Can be resolved by following command in mysql prompt.

```
repair table 'dev.bank_accounts';
```

Internally, mysql trys to recover the data from MyISAM storage engine of mysql.

Caution - Please take a back up of the table before doing a repair, As the repair might cause a data loss.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Go to structure of the table and scroll down and click on optimize option. It will repair your table and will fix this issue.