# Problems in creating stored procedure in phpmyadmin, column count mysql.proc is incorrect

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

Trying to create simple stored procedure in phpmyadmin through 'Routines' tab as

`BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_user;
END`

throws errors as 
Column count of mysql.proc is wrong,expected 21 found 20, please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error

What I already tried

1 - tried couple of way to use mysql_upgrade , but as I am using xampp I was not able to find a way to upgrade mysql as mysql is replaced by maridb

2 - tried upgrading phpmyadmin to latest by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131029/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-xampp-to-latest)

3 - Uninstalled xampp and installed latest version '7.3.8'

4 - Formatted the system and installed latest ubuntu '19.04' (lol that was't needed though)

5 - tried to make changes in mysql.proc, added new column as 'aggregate'  , which I found [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlproc-table/) now which throws error as `can not load from mysql.proc, the table is probably corrupted`

Now I am left with only one option which is uninstall xampp and install mysql workbench.

I am using xampp as most of my projects are php based, 
How can I use mysql_upgrade
Or can fix this issue
Any help would really appreciate.

Comment: What happens when you replace `*` with explicitly named columns?

Comment: It throws the same error as `column count of mysql.proc is wrong,expected 21 found 20, please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error`

Comment: I tells you a row number whoch ever is truncated, that wound change by installing anything. check the row in the error message.

Comment: @nbk `mysql.proc` has every row as per [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlproc-table/) except `aggregate`, which I tried to add in mysql.proc which then throws error as `can not load from mysql.proc, the table is probably corrupted`

Comment: try this one please https://stackoverflow.com/a/31140127/5193536

Comment: @nbk thanks for commenting, I tried to repair the table as given in the link, however the error stays as it is, still throwing `column count of mysql.proc is wrong,expected 21 found 20, please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error`

Comment: What happens when you replace * with just one named column? Does the error still mention 20 columns?

Comment: yes sir, the error still remains as it is

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for commenting @nbk
your link gave me a way to fix this issue
Any one who is facing same issue here is the answer
you can access mysql in the terminal using

1. `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p`
2. after that enter the mysql user password if it worked well then type exit
3. and now type `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p` , enter your password and tadam , here is your mysql upgraded

really appreciate your help @Bohemian, @nbk,
Now I am able to create the Stored Procedure without facing any issue

Comment: Using absolute path at 1st step would make it `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p` (notice the `/` at the beginning). Default password for `xampp` is empty, so you can press enter without typing any password when prompted. Also, for the 3rd step to work, you'll have to `cd` into `/opt/lampp/bin` first, or you can do `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p`.