# MySQL proc table getting crashed frequently

Tags: mysql

One of my MySQL server is frequently getting crashed with the below error. I repaired the table but please help me to understand the reason for crash and prevent it.

```
    Table './mysql/proc' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
+------------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                             |
+------------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Wrong bytesec: 116-114- 97 at 1849604; Skipped       |
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Found block that points outside data file at 1856336 |
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Wrong bytesec:  54- 53- 46 at 2513660; Skipped       |
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Found block that points outside data file at 1900432 |
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Found block that points outside data file at 1972664 |
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Wrong bytesec: 116-114- 97 at 1849604; Skipped       |
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Found block that points outside data file at 2586424 |
| mysql.proc | repair | info     | Found block that points outside data file at 2621952 |
| mysql.proc | repair | warning  | Number of rows changed from 157 to 146               |
| mysql.proc | repair | status   | OK                                                   |
+------------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Server is MySQL 5.7.27 community edition and database has got so many partitions and stored procedures.

Thank you,
Peter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table './mysql/proc' is marked as crashed and should be repaired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139397/table-mysql-proc-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired)

Comment: I could repair the table to fix the issue, but looking for the reason why its happening

Comment: I think a stored procedure getting crashed and that cause this problem in mysql.proc table. And I recommend for you to check all site error logs which uses this database server. The source of the problem could easily be elsewhere